# Is there a way to migrate an existing matrix-synapse user database to OpenLDAP?

Tags: openldap, migration, matrix

I am looking for a way to migrate a huge [Synapse](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse) home server database to OpenLDAP without resetting the users' passwords. Migration to LDAP is necessary as we would like to integrate all our online services into each other

Therefore, I am looking for a way to make OpenLDAP understand Synapse's password hashes.

Synapses hashing algorithm is explained [here](https://github.com/matrix-org/synapse/blob/ff40c8099d29dc429b51c1c4717f56ce429bbf29/scripts/hash_password#L74):

```python
pw = unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", password)

hashed = bcrypt.hashpw(
    pw.encode('utf8') + password_pepper.encode("utf8"),
    bcrypt.gensalt(bcrypt_rounds),
).decode('ascii')
```

Is it possible to implement such a hashing on OpenLDAP or any other open source LDAP server?

Answer (score 1):

If bcrypt is a valid algorithm for the underlying system it should work as part of [OpenLDAP's CRYPT password storage scheme](https://openldap.org/doc/admin24/security.html#CRYPT%20password%20storage%20scheme).

If for instance your existing password hashes look like [`$2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt#Description) you should be able to set the `userPassword` attribute OpenLDAP to `{CRYPT}$2a$10$N9qo8uLOickgx2ZMRZoMyeIjZAgcfl7p92ldGxad68LJZdL17lhWy` and then authenticate.
(If you're doing this on the commandline make sure that the `$text` isn't interpreted as a shell variable before being input into the database.)

Comment: They are `$2b$12$...hash...` but otherwise this ought to work, at least on a modern Linux system.

Comment: I am given the following error by OpenLDAP when checking the password: `Unrecognized error number: 8192: crypt(): Supplied salt is not valid for DES. Possible bug in provided salt format.`

Comment: @TheOneWithTheBraid Were you able to figure out a solution?